# css overlapping circle and text box

Tags: css

I am trying to produce this effect with CSS. I have tried creating a box with a triangle and then using negative margin to overlap it onto the circle, but cannot get it right.

[image]

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: your image doesn't work and you need to post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/n3w0tztv/

Getting the circle to stay vertically centered and have the text container min-height the height of circle is tricky and is not worked out in this example. A cheap fix is adding `align-items: center` to `.container` at a breakpoint with @media.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-right: -17px;
  background-color: #ec847c;;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.right {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4ca132;
}
.square {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.square-top { top: 0; }
.square-btm { bottom: 0; }

.square::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(2);
  background-color: #4ca132;
  z-index: 1;
}

.square-top::before { top: 50%; left: 50%; }
.square-btm::before { bottom: 50%; left: 50%; }

.text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="square square-top"></div>
    <div class="square square-btm"></div>
    <div class="text">
Roles play an extremely important part in family funtion.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```